# How do I make a discord bot send a DM to someone mentioned in the command, using java script?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to create a command for my bot that sends a message to someone in their DMs, by having their username mentioned in the command. How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `message.mentions` to get the first person mentioned and send them a message with user.send()

```js
message.mentions.members.first().send("Your message here")
```